# How to modify a parameter passed into a Python object?

Tags: python

In the Python3 script below, I want to pass in a list into an object to be modified, i.e., I want `[5]` to be printed in the console. How do I do that (without returning anything from `fun()`)?

```
class Solution:
    def fun(self, b) -> None:
        b = [5]

orig_b = [1,2,3]
S = Solution()
S.fun(orig_b)
print(orig_b)
```

Comment: You need to mutate the list passed as b, not just assign a _new_ list to that name inside the method.

Comment: Python simply does not Pascal-style out parameters like this. Read https://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html. `fun` has no way of knowing if a variable was even *involved* with the call. You could have written `S.fun([1,2,3])`.

Comment: You can mutate the list with `b[:] = [5]`

Comment: ("does not *support*", above)

Comment: You should avoid doing stuff like that. A method of a class that just randomly mutates a list that was passed as a parameter is pretty bad for readability and will probably make a lot of people using your code freak out...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could also add an `__init__(self)` method.

```
class Solution:

    def __init__(self, b) -> None:
        self.b = b

    def fun(self) -> None:
        self.b = [5]

orig_b = [1,2,3]
S = Solution(orig_b)
S.fun()
print(S.b)
```